# regex - deleting part of url

Tags: c#, regex

How can I delete with regex from URL (string) 
`http://test.com/org/category,1/2`, this part: 
`/2` or `/2/`, with C# language

Of course, there will be numbers like `category,1/412/`, `category,1/521`, `category,1/infinity..`

How can I do this with regex?

Comment: that depends on what criteria you want to remove by. do you want to get rid of the last segment of a string which begins with `'/'`?

Comment: I want to delete segment/segments with `int` between `/abc/`, where `abc` is of course int type.

Comment: but, `"infinity"`? that's ... not really an `int`.

Comment: `category,1/infinity` => I mean very very large `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want to replace `/\d+/?$` with empty string.

You could do that with:

```
url = Regex.Replace(url, @"/\d+/?$", "");
```

Comment: Could you explain me step by step elements of this regex `/\d+/?$` ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `\d` matches a "digit" character; `+` is equivalent to `{1,}`, one or more repetitions of the previous group. Thus, `/`, one or more digits, zero or one `/` (because of `?`), end of line `$`.

Comment: @whoah, it's as sreservoir explained it, with minor correction, `$` in this case matches end of string (or end of line at end of string).